# How to load JSON array to translate AngularJS webpage with Angular-Translate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-translate

I am still learning AngularJS heavily so pardon all my bad quality code/lack of knowledge.

**What I want to do**

I want to translate my webpage into 2 languages. It currently works when I translate static content using *Angular-Translate* in the **index.html**. Like this

```
function translateConfiguration($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy(null);

    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      files: [{
        prefix: '../JSON/locale-',
        suffix: '.json'
      }]
});

$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
$translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en');
```

};

I load my simple **JSON files** for EN and RU locales, structured like this

```
{
 "HEADING" : "Lorem",
 "TEXT" : "Ipsum"
}
```

Then I access the variables through Angular-translate directive

```
<h1 class="z-logo header-text md-display-1" translate="HEADING">
</h1>
```

All works as it should.

***I want to be able to do the same with my custom directives and ng-repeat.***

**The issue**

I have multiple custom directives in my AngularJS website. For instance

```
<about-card flex="33" flex-xs="100" flex-sm="100" class="center-content" ng-repeat="data in aboutCardCtrl.info">
</about-card>
```

Here is the template code that  loads through the custom directive and retrieves information from the JSON file

```
<md-card class="card-bg card-height">
  <md-card-title layout="column" class="about-card">
    <md-card-title-media class="center-elements">
      <img class="md-media-lg" ng-src="{{data.image}}" alt="{{data.imageAlt}}"/>
    </md-card-title-media>
    <md-card-title-text>
      <div class="md-headline card-title-padding">{{data.heading}}</div>
    </md-card-title-text>
  </md-card-title>
  <md-card-content>
    {{data.content | translate}}
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Here is the **directive**

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('webApp')
    .directive('aboutCard', aboutCard);

  function aboutCard() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      priority: 1001,
      templateUrl: '../TEMPLATES/about.html',
      controller: 'aboutCardController',
      controllerAs: 'aboutCardCtrl'
    };
  };
})();
```

Here is the **controller**

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

  angular
    .module('webApp')
    .controller('aboutCardController', aboutCardController);

  aboutCardController.$inject = ['JsonData', '$translate'];

  function aboutCardController(JsonData, $translate) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.pathToJson = '../JSON/about-en.json';
    vm.info = [];

    JsonData.all(vm.pathToJson).then(function(response) {
      vm.info = response.data.information;
    });
  };
})();
```

Here is the **JSON file**

```
  {
      "information": [{
        "heading": "Reliability",
        "content": "Our partners have been working on the market for over 10 years",
        "image": "../IMG/shield.svg",
        "imageAlt": "Reliability Image"
      }, {
        "heading": "Professionalism",
        "content": "We are ready to provide profesional opinion for our clients to ensure the right choice",
        "image": "../IMG/people.svg",
        "imageAlt": "Professionalism Image"
      }, {
        "heading": "Development",
        "content": "Organization of educational programs in collaboration with our partners",
        "image": "../IMG/cogwheel.svg",
        "imageAlt": "Development Image"
      }]
    }
```

Here I suppose I lack the brainpower to understand how I can load my JSON files and switch between them in the custom directive with `ng-repeat`. Since The format of the JSON is different.

I've been going through Angular-Translate wiki pages, but all examples feature only *index.html* and main *app.js* files and I hardly seem to be able to find/understand examples found in google search like these

https://technpol.wordpress.com/2013/11/02/adding-translation-using-angular-translate-to-an-angularjs-app/

https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate/issues/1154

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic loader instead of static.

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('$translatePartialLoader', {
  urlTemplate: 'JSON/{part}/{lang}.json'
});
```

And then load JSON that you need like this:

```
$translatePartialLoader.addPart('about');
```

Language prefix will be automatically add to the path.

Comment: I assume I am using it instead of $http to get the json file right? How about accessing json after that? Do I just add translate directive and that's it?

Comment: Yes. After you add part, in your view just use translate directive or filter and thats all. And you can add part in any time, and then use it.

Comment: Alright, thanks. I am going to try this once I get back home in an hour.

Comment: Alright, I got the loader working but how do I get the array data from the JSON after $translatePartialLoader.addPart('about');? Something like this or vm.info = $translatePartialLoader.addPart('about'); ?